# .Net: Background Worker and multiple CPU

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I am using the `BackgroundWorker` to do some heavy stuff in the background so that the UI does not become unresponsive.

But today I noticed that when I run my program, only one of the two CPUs is being used.

Is there any way to use *all* CPUs with the `BackgroundWorker`?

[image]

Here is my simplified code, just if you are curious!

---

```
private System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker bwPatchApplier;

this.bwPatchApplier.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
this.bwPatchApplier.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.bwPatchApplier_DoWork);
this.bwPatchApplier.ProgressChanged += new System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventHandler(this.bwPatchApplier_ProgressChanged);
this.bwPatchApplier.RunWorkerCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this.bwPatchApplier_RunWorkerCompleted);
```

---

```
private void bwPatchApplier_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    string pc1WorkflowName;
    string pc2WorkflowName;

    if (!GetWorkflowSettings(out pc1WorkflowName, out pc2WorkflowName)) return;

    int progressPercentage = 0;
    var weWorkspaces = (List<WEWorkspace>) e.Argument;

    foreach (WEWorkspace weWorkspace in weWorkspaces)
    {
        using (var spSite = new SPSite(weWorkspace.SiteId))
        {
            foreach (SPWeb web in spSite.AllWebs)
            {
                using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb(web.ID))
                {
                    PrintHeader(spWeb.ID, spWeb.Title, spWeb.Url, bwPatchApplier);

                    try
                    {
                        for (int index = 0; index < spWeb.Lists.Count; index++)
                        {
                            SPList spList = spWeb.Lists[index];

                            if (spList.Hidden) continue;

                            string listName = spList.Title;

                            if (listName.Equals("PC1") || listName.Equals("PC2"))
                            {
                                #region STEP 1

                                // STEP 1: Remove Workflow

                                #endregion

                                #region STEP 2

                                // STEP 2: Add Events: Adding & Updating

                                #endregion
                            }

                            if ((uint) spList.BaseTemplate == 10135 || (uint) spList.BaseTemplate == 10134)
                            {
                                #region STEP 3

                                // STEP 3: Configure Custom AssignedToEmail Property

                                #endregion

                                #region STEP 4

                                if (enableAssignToEmail)
                                {
                                    // STEP 4: Install AssignedTo events to Work lists
                                }

                                #endregion
                            }

                            #region STEP 5

                            // STEP 5 Install Notification Events

                            #endregion

                            #region STEP 6

                            // STEP 6 Install Report List Events

                            #endregion

                            progressPercentage += TotalSteps;
                            UpdatePercentage(progressPercentage, bwPatchApplier);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                        progressPercentage += TotalSteps;
                        UpdatePercentage(progressPercentage, bwPatchApplier);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    PrintMessage(string.Empty, bwPatchApplier);
    PrintMessage("*** Process Completed", bwPatchApplier);

    UpdateStatus("Process Completed", bwPatchApplier);
}
```

---

Thanks a lot for looking into this :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `BackgroundWorker` does its work within a single background (ThreadPool) thread.  As such, if it's computationally heavy, it'll use one CPU heavily.  The UI thread is still running on the second, but is probably (like most user interface work) spending almost all of its time idle waiting for input (which is a good thing).

If you want to split your work up to use more than one CPU, you'll need to use some other techniques.  This could be multiple `BackgroundWorker` components, each doing some work, or using the ThreadPool directly.  Parallel programming has been simplified in .NET 4 via the TPL, which is likely a very good option.  For details, you can see [my series on the TPL](http://reedcopsey.com/series/parallelism-in-net4/) or [MSDN's page on the Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Each **BackgroundWorker** uses only a single thread to do the stuff you tell it to do.  To take advantage of multiple cores, you would need multiple threads.  That would mean either multiple **BackgroundWorkers** or spawning multiple threads from within your **DoWork** method.

Answer (score 3):

The backgroundworker, by itself, only provides one additional thread of execution. It's purpose is to get things off the UI thread, and it's very good at that job.  If you want more threads, you need to provide them yourself.

It would be tempting here to build a method that accepts an SPWeb argument, and just call Thread.Start() over and over for each object; then finish with Thread.Join() or WaitAll() to wait for them to finish at the end of the BackgroundWorker.  However, this would be a bad idea because you'll lose efficiency as the operating system spends time performing context switches among all the threads.

Instead, you want to force your system to run in only a few threads, but at least two (in this case). A good rule of thumb is (2n - 1), where "n" is the number of processor cores you have... but there are all kinds of cases where you want to break this rule.  You can implement this by using a ThreadPool, by iterating over your SPWeb objects and adding them to a queue that you keep pulling from, or other means such as the TPL.

Answer (score 1):

The `BackgroundWorker` is running a new thread on the second CPU core, leaving the UI responsive.

If you're using .NET 4, look into using the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx), which could give you better results and utilize both cores.

Answer (score 0):

The BackgroundWorker itself is only creating a single thread apart from your main UI to do work in - it's not trying to parallelize the operations within that work thread. If you want to spread your work across multiple work threads you should look into using the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx). Bear in mind that not all tasks translate well to parallel execution, so if freeing the UI is your only goal this may already be the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

There are potential pitfalls to this, but you might get some mileage out of utilizing Parallel.ForEach:

Instead of

```
foreach (SPWeb web in spSite.AllWebs)
{
    //Your loop code here
}
```

You could:

```
Parallel.Foreach(spSite.AllWebs, web =>
        {
          //Your loop code here
        });
```

This basically creates a Task (from the Task API in .NET 4.0) from each item and schedules that work with the TaskPool, which will give you some of the parallelism you will need to take advantage of those cores.

You will have to fix the inevitable concurrency problems that might arise from this, but it's a good starting point. You are going to at least fix the fact that you are maintaining a shared state across threads (the progress counter). Here's some guidance on that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997392.aspx